# CasperJS for loop produces same result in chunks of three - with time delay

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous, web-scraping, casperjs

I'm using CasperJS to scrape a website for data.  My program finds an `<a>` tag in a table, clicks it, fetches some data from the new page, returns to the previous page and repeats the process for the next `<a>` tag.

All was going well until I stumbled upon the strangest problem: a CasperJS for loop produces the same result in chunks of three.  Whatever the first iteration returns, the next two iterations will return the same data.  It repeats this process

**Example**

This loop...

```
casper.then(function() {
  var i = 1;
  var j = 9;
  var bookingNumber = 0;
  var location = '';

  for (; i <= j;) {
    (function(index, max) {
      casper.then(function() {
        casper.waitForSelector(x('//*[@id="ListInmateNames"]/table'), function() {
          casper.click(x('//*[@id="ListInmateNames"]/table/tbody/tr[' + index + ']/td[1]/a'));
          this.echo('Loading details for inmate ' + index + ' of ' + max + '...', 'COMMENT');
        });
      });

      casper.then(function() {
        casper.waitForSelector(x('//*[@id="pnlResults"]/div[2]'), function() {
          bookingNumber = casper.fetchText(x('//*[@id="lblResults"]'));
          location = casper.fetchText(x('//*[@id="hlHousingLocation"]'));

          this.echo(bookingNumber);
          this.echo(location);
        });
      });

      casper.then(function() {
        casper.back();
      });

    })(i, j);

    i++;
  }
});
```

...produces this output.

```
> Loading details for inmate 1 of 9... 2985842 Theo Lacy Facility

> Loading details for inmate 2 of 9... 2985842 Theo Lacy Facility

> Loading details for inmate 3 of 9... 2985842 Theo Lacy Facility

> Loading details for inmate 4 of 9...

> Loading details for inmate 5 of 9...

> Loading details for inmate 6 of 9...

> Loading details for inmate 7 of 9... 2993051 Central Mens Jail

> Loading details for inmate 8 of 9... 2993051 Central Mens Jail

> Loading details for inmate 9 of 9... 2993051 Central Mens Jail
```

**What makes it really weird (and why I'm asking on SO)**

It will return the same data in chunks of three *no matter what*.  I sat threw hundreds of iterations, and it still produced the same patterned output.  I thought the asynchronous nature of CasperJS running with synchronous JavaScript would not consistently produce this pattern.  But it does.

Interestingly enough, there's a slight delay between the chunks of output.  The program will echo iterations 1-3, then wait a second, then echo iterations 4-6, then wait a second.  This is a consistent behavior.

Also, **incrementing the i++ counter *twice* in the for loop still produces the same chunks-of-three patterned output behavior**, meaning incrementing the i++ twice in the loop produces this output...

```
> Loading details for inmate 1 of 9... 2985842 Theo Lacy Facility

> Loading details for inmate 3 of 9... 2985842 Theo Lacy Facility

> Loading details for inmate 5 of 9... 2985842 Theo Lacy Facility
```

...hopefully you get the idea.

**What I've tried**

- Shifting the i++ counter to different code blocks.
- Placing the i++ counter in the for loop as `for (; i <= j; i++)` and removing the `i++` statement
- Declaring, initializing, and reassigning the four variables (i, j, bookingNumber, location) in different code blocks
- Declaring the variables with `const` or `let`
- Renaming `index` and `max` to `i` and `j` respectively
- Removing the for loop and hardcoding my program, which runs perfectly

---

**TL;DR**: My CasperJS for-loop consistently produces output in chunks of three.  The second and third iterations' output will be whatever the first iteration's was.  Under no circumstances does that ever change.

If anyone can help me and stop me from shooting myself and ending my misery with this problem that has been haunting my dreams, that would be amazing and I'll hand-deliver you a cookie.